# Ubuntu 18.04 two nvidia cards can't select one for Physx only

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics

So I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04 on a system that has two NVidia cards that are considered old to today's standards. The NVidia cards are: Geforce GTX 460 and Geforce GTX 550 Ti. I would like to set the Geforce GTX 550 Ti for display and use the Geforce GTX 460 for Physx. The NVidia drivers were installed using ubuntu-drivers autoinstall. I have one monitor connected to one of the DVI ports on the GTX 460. When I open Software & Updates and select the "Additional Drivers" tab I see the NVidia GTX 550 Ti driver selected. When I launch the NVidia-Settings application I can see both NVidia video cards, but I cannot find a way to select which card I want to use for Physx and the other one for display like you can do in Windows.
My primary use for this system is simply to play CounterStrike and do light video editing.